# Either no records were produced by the task since the last offset commit or every record has been filtered out

Tags: mysql, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm working on a task to setup jdbc kafka connector on my local machine. I went through the setup step by step one by one:

```
➜  bin ./zookeeper-server-start.sh ../config/zookeeper.properties
➜  bin ./kafka-topics.sh --create --topic quickstart-events --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
➜  bin  ./connect-distributed.sh ../config/connect-distributed.properties
```

and ran Kafka server successfully.

Finally registered the jdbc kafka connector using curl command:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8083/connectors -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
        "name": "jdbc_source_mysql_01",
        "config": {
                "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
                "connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/neo_table”,
                "connection.user": “root”,
                "connection.password": "xxx",
                "topic.prefix": "saif-test",
                "mode":"bulk",
                "poll.interval.ms" : 3600000
                }
        }'
```

And finally ran the consumer:

```
 ➜  bin sh kafka-console-consumer.sh --topic saif-test  --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
```

but consumer is sitting their idle, not printing any messages, and kafka server is printing error messages:

> [2022-04-06 08:53:43,060] INFO [jdbc_source_mysql_01|task-0|offsets]
> WorkerSourceTask{id=jdbc_source_mysql_01-0} Either no records were
> produced by the task since the last offset commit, or every record has
> been filtered out by a transformation or dropped due to transformation
> or conversion errors.
> (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:484)

```
➜  bin sh kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server=localhost:9092 --list
__consumer_offsets
connect-configs
connect-offsets
connect-status
neo_table
neo_tableneo_table
neo_tablesys_config
quickstart-events
saif-test
saif-testneo_table
saif-testsys_config
```

Comment: Please show `kafka-topics --list` output. `saif-test` is a **prefix**, not the actual topic name itself

Comment: Have you tried running `kafka-console-consumer --topic saif-testneo_table --bootstrap-server=localhost:9092 --from-beginning`? Also, you've shown an INFO message from connect, not any real ERROR logs that might have occurred

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this generic error when trying to run KafkaMirrorMaker2 from one  Strimzi cluster to another.

My issue was resolved by providing more "Describe" privileges on the source cluster to allow for all topics to described rather than just the one to mirror.  Errors were in the source, which in my case was the Kafka cluster broker logs.